# update database with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My database table has 2 fields: `id` (int) and `state` (enum -> 0,1).

What I need to do is to update my database (my `state` field) with the state of a `checkbox` (`0` for empty, `1` for checked).

To show each of the fields in my database, I use a loop:

**Loop:**

```
<?php
foreach ( $posts_array as $module )
{
?>
    <h2><?php echo $module->titre; ?></h2>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx_<?php echo $module->id; ?>"> id="chkbx_<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"> On/Off <br />
<?php
}
?>
```

**My update file:**

```
foreach ($_GET['onoffswitch-checkbox'] as $id => $state)
{
    // $_GET['onoffswitch-checkbox'] = class for all my checkboxed
    // $id = my database row id
    // $state = on/off
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE records SET id='$id' WHERE state='$state'", $conn) or die (mysql_error($conn));
    $id++;
}
```

Where I need help is the AJAX part of the code. I'm guessing it looks something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("onoffswitch-checkbox").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#state_span").load("module_update.php?"+id); 
    }
}
```

I've been looking around, seen a few examples where the we could do so with a submit button, but none where the information is automatically recorded when clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Was this answer useful?

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I needed. Thanks, Sergio !
My major problem was the syntax, as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".onoffswitch-checkbox").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;  //changed here also, just because jQuery is not needed here
        var state = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        $("#state_span").load("module_update.php?id="+id+"&state="+state); 
    }
}
```

Changed 3 things:

- added a dot in `$("onoffswitch-checkbox")` so its now `$(".onoffswitch-checkbox")`
- added `id=` after `module_update.php?` and before `id` value.
- since you need `state` also I added that also with a `&` to separate the values for `$_GET` in php to separate them

**PHP**

I don't know what you mean with `$_GET['onoffswitch-checkbox']` in the php, maybe a mistake? My suggestion does not need it anyway, neither does your mysql query.

Since you will be only clicking one at a time I see no need for the `foreach` loop in php, so you could do this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$state= $_GET['state'];
// $_GET['onoffswitch-checkbox'] ?? I don't think you need this...
// $id = my database row id
// $state = on/off
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE records SET id='$id' WHERE state='$state'", $conn) or die (mysql_error($conn));
$id++;
```