# update several records at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form with dynamic table (PHP/MYSQL) where some records are been show with checbox and i want to update this records with one button click by selecting or deselecting the checkboxes.
My checkbox checked value is set to 2, blank will be 1 (default on mysql table).

Any sugestion or example for this updates?

My table

```
ID | CHKBOX1 | CHKBOX2 | CHKBOX3 | CHKBOX4
1  |   x     |    X    |         |    X
2  |   x     |         |    X    |    X
3  |         |    X    |         |    X
4  |   x     |         |         |    X
```

Comment: That would require ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update database with checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705369/update-database-with-checkbox)